# issue with docker on a vps server

Tags: laravel, apache, docker, vps

i'm new to **Docker** and facing with an issue for days and i don't know how to manage that. here is the situation;
i have a sudoer user in a vps server that runs such services like apache2 and mysql and ... and also serves couple application that i don't want to hurt them by upgrade or change services like php version or change web server from apache to nginx.
i want to serve a laravel application in docker and i built this `docker-compose.prod.yml` file in my project root folder that lives in `/home/myUser/www/laravelProject` (contains laravel application):

```
version : '3'

networks:
  laravel:
volumes :
  dbdata:
    driver: local

services:
  nginx:
    image         : nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports         :
    - "8080:80"
    volumes       :
      - ./:/var/www/html ## i think it would make sens if i do like ./:/home/myuser/www/laravelProject ???!!!
      - ./nginx/default.prod.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on    :
      - php
      - mysql
      - redis
      - artisan
    networks      :
      - laravel

mysql      :
  image         : mysql:5.7.29
  container_name: mysql
  restart       : unless-stopped
  tty           : true
  ports         :
    - "4406:3306"
  environment   :
    MYSQL_DATABASE     : ${DB_DATABASE}
    MYSQL_USER         : ${DB_USERNAME}
    MYSQL_PASSWORD     : ${DB_PASSWORD}
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    SERVICE_TAGS       : dev
    SERVICE_NAME       : mysql
  volumes       :
    - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
  networks      :
    - laravel

php        :
  build         :
    context   : .
    dockerfile: php.prod.dockerFile
  container_name: php
  volumes       :
    - ./:/var/www/html
  ports         :
    - "9000:9000"
  networks      :
    - laravel

artisan    :
  build         :
    context   : .
    dockerfile: php.dockerfile
  container_name: artisan
  volumes       :
    - ./:/var/www/html
  depends_on    :
    - mysql
  working_dir   : /var/www/html
  entrypoint    : ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
  networks      :
    - laravel

redis      :
  container_name: redis
  image         : redis
  ports         :
    - "6379:6379"
  volumes       :
    - ./:/data
  entrypoint    : redis-server --appendonly yes
  restart       : always
  networks      :
    - laravel
```

i'm sorry i think i missed tab's and spaces. however, and this is my php.prod.dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /home/www/html // again it's not supposed to be /home/myUser/www/project ???!!!

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www // i don't really have any sense why i'm doing this !!
```

i build the containers successfully using command (in my project root):

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml  up  -d --build`

and the default.prod.nginx file is :

```
server {
listen 80;
index index.php index.html;
server_name api.myUser.com www.api.myUser.com;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
root /var/www/html/public;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
}
```

unfortunately when i try to reach to the endpoint api.myUser.com:8080 i see

```
This site can’t be reached
http://api.myUser.com:8080/ is unreachable.
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

what i'm missing ?
(sorry for my english)

EDIT: here is the output of docker-compose up --build

```
Creating network "kooche-mobl_laravel" with the default driver
Building php
Step 1/4 : FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
---> f9f075c5a926
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /var/www/html
---> Using cache
---> 5478beb70e23
Step 3/4 : RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
---> Using cache
---> 049d5b4134d8
Step 4/4 : RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
---> Using cache
---> b697f0fb62a1
Successfully built b697f0fb62a1
Successfully tagged kooche-mobl_php:latest
Building artisan
Step 1/4 : FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
---> f9f075c5a926
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /var/www/html
---> Using cache
---> 5478beb70e23
Step 3/4 : RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
---> Using cache
---> 049d5b4134d8
Step 4/4 : RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
---> Using cache
---> b697f0fb62a1
Successfully built b697f0fb62a1
Successfully tagged kooche-mobl_artisan:latest
Creating redis ... done
Creating mysql ... done
Creating php   ... done
Creating artisan ... done
Creating nginx   ... done
Attaching to redis, php, mysql, artisan, nginx
mysql          | 2020-09-04 06:46:10+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]:Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.29-1debian10 started.
mysql          | 2020-09-04 06:46:10+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]:Switching to dedicated user 'mysql' 
mysql          | 2020-09-04 06:46:10+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]:Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.29-1debian10 started.
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.850419Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use -- explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.857132Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.29-log) starting as process 1 ...
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.866317Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.866418Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.866455Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.866506Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.866533Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11 
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.866578Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.868019Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.868769Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.876267Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.918223Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.936304Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:11.955456Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.004799Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.004958Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.055925Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.058036Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo 
rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.058061Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.059038Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.109390Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.29 started; log sequence number 12758905
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.110224Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.115113Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.126409Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200904  6:46:12
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.137920Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.138013Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.139676Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.139893Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.141123Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.141277Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.141345Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.141398Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.168549Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql          | 2020-09-04T06:46:12.169118Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql          | Version: '5.7.29-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
nginx          | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not 
empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx          | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx          | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
php            | [04-Sep-2020 06:46:10] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
php            | [04-Sep-2020 06:46:10] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
nginx          | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
redis          | 1:C 04 Sep 2020 06:46:10.064 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis          | 1:C 04 Sep 2020 06:46:10.064 # Redis version=6.0.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis          | 1:C 04 Sep 2020 06:46:10.064 # Configuration loaded
redis          | 1:M 04 Sep 2020 06:46:10.068 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis          | 1:M 04 Sep 2020 06:46:10.068 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
redis          | 1:M 04 Sep 2020 06:46:10.068 # Server initialized
redis          | 1:M 04 Sep 2020 06:46:10.068 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.

redis          | 1:M 04 Sep 2020 06:46:10.070 * Ready to accept connections
nginx          | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: error: 
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packages version
nginx          | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker- 
entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx          | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready 
for start up
```

i've also this line on `netstat -tulnp | grep 8080`

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      16093/docker-proxy
```

EDIT 2:

and about the firewall (iptables)
`cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables |grep ACCEPT`
its out put

```
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [884:49904]
:INPUT ACCEPT [262:14960]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [60:4106]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [77:5110]
:INPUT ACCEPT [247:22593]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [199:50843]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8090 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8090 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-4a4e80432e3f -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-4a4e80432e3f ! -o br-4a4e80432e3f -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-4a4e80432e3f -o br-4a4e80432e3f -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-8e73d0dbe1df -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-8e73d0dbe1df ! -o br-8e73d0dbe1df -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-8e73d0dbe1df -o br-8e73d0dbe1df -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m owner --gid-owner 209 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m owner --gid-owner 12 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m owner --uid-owner 201 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m owner --uid-owner 0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 192.168.32.2/32 ! -i br-4a4e80432e3f -o br-4a4e80432e3f 
-p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 192.168.32.3/32 ! -i br-4a4e80432e3f -o br-4a4e80432e3f 
-p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 192.168.32.4/32 ! -i br-4a4e80432e3f -o br-4a4e80432e3f 
-p tcp -m tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 192.168.32.6/32 ! -i br-4a4e80432e3f -o br-4a4e80432e3f 
-p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

i think it seems ok, but when i try `telnet myPort 8080`

says:

`telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host`

Comment: Is the `api.myUser.com` an existing domain name (just obfuscated for the question) or something you came up with?

Comment: Yes marko, it is actualy a valid domain. I didn't mention the na , i thought its easier to read myUser.com

Comment: I'm not sure which cloud provider you are using, but is port 8080 allowed?

Comment: Marko , i tried other ports too such 9000 , 8000 but no luck. You know, im not sure if trafic comes to the container or not. Actualy im looking for some way to route the trafic from apache too my containers. Is everything ok with my code ? . Did i miss something you think ?

Comment: You said you were using a VPS. Does the VPS have any kind of configuration for which ports are allowed/denied? I'm not sure what is wrong, but I would suspect it's the firewall for now. You could add the output of the `docker compose up --build` to the question, there might be something that could give us a clue what's wrong.

Comment: @MarkoE here is the output , im not sure about firewall i think i should check with the host provider

Comment: @MarkoE also i checked the error nginx's giving [github](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/419)

Comment: ANY HELP... !!!